Can fractal sets be crazily similar and disjoint?
Is there a pair of sets $A,B$ in $[0,1]$, such that:

$0<\mathcal{H}^d(A),\mathcal{H}^d(B)<+\infty$ for some $d\in\langle 0,1\rangle$
$\mathcal{H}^d(A\cap[a,b])=\mathcal{H}^d(B\cap[a,b])$ for all $a,b\in[0,1]$
$A\cap B=\emptyset$

I believe this might be the case for some sort of "universally" distributed set $A$ such that $\mathcal{H}^d(A\cap [a,b])=c(b-a)$ for some fixed constant $c>0$ and $a<b$ in $[0,1]$, while $B$ would be some kind of a shift of $A$ (modulo $1$). However, what kind of set this could be, and would shifting it result in a disjoint set (or taking $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus A$ would result in two sets with nonzero measure)?
Thank you!
Edit: I suspect that by the definition of Hausdorff measure, $\mathcal{H}^d_\delta(A)=\mathcal{H}^d_\delta(B)=\mathcal{H}^d_\delta(A\cup B)$ which would obviously imply $2\mathcal{H}^d(A)=\mathcal{H}^d(A\cup B)=\mathcal{H}^d(A)$, an apparent contradiction. Nevertheless, I am unsure about this approach and the nature of the formal proof for it. I'd be grateful for any kind of help :)
